# How do we write a CSS "block-level-style" within an inline style attribute tag?

Tags: html, css, google-sites

Hi all I'm using Google Sites and I want to write a very simple CSS script in my page:

```
<style>p {background:#ccc;}</style>
```

However, Google removes all style tags. The solution they provide is to put our styles in an inline attribute as such:

```
<div style="...">
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<div style="p {background:#ccc;}">
```

I was wondering how do we write a CSS "block-level-styles" within an inline style attribute tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Inline styles can only contain property-value declarations; they can't contain declaration blocks or selectors.

You would have to apply the `background:#ccc` inline style to all the `p` elements, unfortunately...

Comment: I don't mind if that's a solution but it isn't because not all `p` elements are supplied by me. It's like part of the template

Comment: @Pacerier - Can you apply the styles after the page is loaded via JavaScript? It will result in a flash of unstyled content, but it sounds like you might have no other option.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Google doesn't make it easy for us to do a simple `alert('Helloworld');`

Comment: You don't need styles for an alert.